# C# Set Methods?

Tags: c#, class, methods

Is there a way to set different methods for a class? So have the preDraw and postDraw methods here be different for different instances of the class?

```
class Scene
{
    public string text;

    public void preDraw() { }
    public void postDraw() { }

    Button[] buttons;

    public Scene(string text)
    {

    }
}


static class Scenes
{
    public static Scene name = new Scene("What is your name?");
    public static Scene age = new Scene("How old are you?");
}
```

where I might be able to set the preDraw method of name something completely different from the preDraw method of age?

Comment: You might need to read about Interfaces - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can make `Scene` and abstract class with abstract methods, then have each implementation of `Scene` would have to have its own implementation of the method.

```
abstract class Scene
{
    public string text;

    public abstract void preDraw();
    public abstract void postDraw();

    Button[] buttons;

    public Scene(string text)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle this you should use inheritance.

I would also use virtual methods, because you might like to have it already written in base class.

I would suggest you to create a base class:

```
public class Scene
{
    public string text;

    public virtual void preDraw() { }
    public virtual void postDraw() { }

    protected Button[] buttons;

    public Scene(string text)
    {

    }
}
```

Then I would create classes that inherit from `Scene`:

```
public class NameScene : Scene
{
    public override void preDraw() { }
    public override void postDraw() { }
}
```

and

```
public class AgeScene : Scene
{
    public override void preDraw() { }
    public override void postDraw() { }
}
```

and finally use it like this:

```
static class Scenes
{
    public static Scene name = new NameScene("What is your name?");
    public static Scene age = new AgeScene("How old are you?");
}
```

Please note that if in an inherited class, it is not necessary to do code modification, You can just skip those methods.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from I am not sure this is the good way to go (you may want to be interested in using polymorphism instead), if you really want to have different method implementation per instance, you can use delegates:

```
class Scene
{
    public string text;

    public Action PreDraw {get; set;}
    public Action PostDraw {get; set;}


    public Scene(string text, Action preDraw)
    {
        text = text;
        PreDraw = preDraw;
    }
}


static class Scenes
{
    public static Scene name = new Scene("What is your name?", () => Console.WriteLine("PreDraw the name."));
    public static Scene age = new Scene("How old are you?", () => Console.WriteLine("PreDraw the age."));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practise in your case: you must use polymorphism
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want every instance has it's own method?You Can use a Delegate to do this.

```
class Scene
{
    public string text;

    public Action preDraw{get;set; }
    public Action postDraw{get;set; }

    Button[] buttons;

    public Scene(string text)
    {

    }
}
static class Scenes
{
    public static Scene name = new Scene("What is your name?");
    name.preDraw=new Action(()=>{Console.WriteLine("preDraw by name");});
    name.postDraw=new Action(()=>{Console.WriteLine("postDrawby name");});
    public static Scene age = new Scene("How old are you?");
    age.preDraw=new Action(()=>{Console.WriteLine("preDraw by age");});
    age.postDraw=new Action(()=>{Console.WriteLine("postDrawby age");});
}
```